# No module named pycurl error even with pycurl instaled

Tags: python, raspbian, pycurl

I want to use pycurl in my first python project on Raspbian but i have some difficulties installing it. During the installation procces (by pip) everything seemed to go well, nothing errored out but when i try to implement it the ide errors out. I've tried a lot of suggested solutions in other treads but I'm geting nowhere.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Hi @Muhaha could you link to the other thread and give a full description of the errors you got?
If you could also post which version you are using and if you are using a virtual environment that would help too!

Comment: I'm using MU IDE in Raspbian (it was supposed to be a quick little project). I've been searching for solution for this problem for a long time so i don't remember all of the threads, sorry. The only error I've got is No module named pycurl. It just can't find it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is no module named pycurl, then the most likely reason for that is the package is its not well installed.

The common reason for that is that your virtual environment is not well activated, so you didn't install it globally and its withing your environment.

If you don't have a virtual environment then you installed your package globally. The most common reason for a no module error is that you installed it in another version of python that you are using in your code.

Double check where you are installing the packages and which version your project is using!